# Converting string to int or double without using library functions in python

Tags: python

I have a question, recently I was asked to convert a string to a number using python without using libraries doing so , while converting positive numbers is quite easy I wonder how can I do it if the number is negative or if the number is double/float type ('23.4556'), so far this is my code:

```
a = '546'
res = 0
value = {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}

for digit in a:
    res = res * 10 + value[digit]

print(res)
```

but the above code will solve the problem only for positive numbers, how can I make it support negative and double/float numbers?

Comment: "I was asked to..."? Sounds like homework (which is fine, and good that you're showing your work so far).

Comment: What steps have you taken to try to incorporate negative numbers? Did you run into issues?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I tried to check the first character if that's a negative number for example:
if a[0] == '-':
 run from the second position of the string to the end
as for double/float number I guess I have to search for the "." character but then again how do I convert it to a number as part of double number (e.g. 24.435)

Comment: ... `float("-657393.09498")` does not use _any_ library ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner so without this :)

Comment: Just in case, you could improve your question adding at the last part : "..without using libraries, functions or built-in functions in python".  It's an interesting question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This code can handle both normal integer and float number in both +ive and -ive case. without using any builtin or library functions.

```
a = '546.246'
integer_value = 0
fraction_value = 0

value = {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}
sign = +1
decimal = False
fraction_counter = 1

for digit in a:
    if digit == '-':    # to Handle if given number is negative
        sign = -1
        continue
    if digit == '.':    # to handle floating point numbers
        decimal = True
        continue
    if decimal:
        fraction_value = (fraction_value * 10) + value[digit]   # Convert floating part
        fraction_counter *= 10
    else:
        integer_value = integer_value * 10 + value[digit]       # Convert integer part


if decimal:     #If given number is decimal, combine both part of number
    integer_value = integer_value + ( fraction_value / fraction_counter )

integer_value = integer_value * sign    #multiply with -1 if number is negative
print(integer_value)
```

Note: This approach is upgrade version of your solution

Example:

`Input : '635'            Output : 635`

`Input : '-635'           Output : -635`

`Input : '635.780'        Output : 635.780`

`Input : '-635.780'       Output : -635.780`

Answer (score 0):

This code will change positive as well as negative numbers

```py
def conv(s):
        rtr, sign=0, 1
        s=s.strip()
        if s[0] in '+-':
           sc, s=s[0], s[1:]
           if sc=='-':
               sign=-1

        for c in s:
                rtr=rtr*10 + ord(c) - ord('0')

         return sign*rtr
```

Comment: I think he is not allowed builtin functions as well, otherwise he could have use typecast directly